# Find the size of a an image sent from Java to PHP as a byte array.

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP, Java is my domain. I have a specific problem that when I upload a picture from my client side to be stored in the database, before saving it I want to calculate the file size and it should be less than 3mb. I am sending this file from Java as a byte array. I Googled around and found that

```
 $result_array = getimagesize($file);
```

can give me the file size, however it takes an argument which has to be a file. How do I do it for a byte array? do I have to convert it first. I beg pardon, this might be a naive question but consider my being new to PHP.

So far my PHP looks like this:

```
<?php

require 'DbConnect.php';


$IMG= $_POST["Image"];
$IMG2= $_POST["Image2"];
$IMG3= $_POST["Image3"];
$IMG4= $_POST["Image4"];
$ID = $_POST["Seller_ID"]; 

$query2 = "INSERT INTO used_cars (Img, Img2, Img3, Img4) VALUES ('$IMG', '$IMG2', '$IMG3', '$IMG4')";


mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error())

?>
```

Comment: Being new to PHP, first of all stop using `mysql_*` extension, it's not safe. learn `mysqli_*` and use `mysqli_query()`. Secondly you can store your byte array as a temporary file on file system and then process like you mentioned

Comment: getimagesize gives the dimensions not filesize. (take a look on count instead)

Comment: Okay I have figured out a way, Ill check the size client side in Java!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ImageMagick.

Read the byte array into an ImageMagick object readimageblob

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php

then read the image information using getimagesize function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagesize.php

You may also want to try a google or stackoverflow search using the BLOB keyword.

Comment: Thanks man, but I have decided to do it client side in Java only. More feasible to check it before uploading.